# Play audio accessed from local drive with embed/object element

Tags: html, audio-streaming

I am using the following code to play an audio file from local drive.

I am not able to access the local drive path.

```
//for firefox
var a = '<object width="100" height="100" type="application/x-mplayer2" type="audio/wav" data="file:///C:\test.wma">';
//for ie
var a = '<embed src="file:///C:\test.wma" controller="true" autoplay="true" autostart="True" type="audio/wav" />';
```

Comment: To play audio with HTML5, you use the <audio> tag, not <object> or <embed>.

Comment: Yes, u are correct.but <audio> is supported after IE 9+.i need in all IE versions.the above code works fine in webcontent folder.but i need to access in local drives..how to do it,let me know??

Comment: It's confusing that you tagged it as HTML5, but it's not HTML5-related at all.  My best guess to get the local URL path is to drag the file into the browser and see what it sets the URL as, or just use relative paths.